# MariaDB executemany on duplicate key in Debian Stretch

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb, insert-update, upsert

Could anyone explain me is it bug or feature?

- Debian Stretch
- mariadb-server-10.1.26
- mariadb-client-10.1.26
- MySQLdb-1.2.5

This python code perfectlly works in Debian Jessie, but failed in Stretch with error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bug_check.py", line 17, in <module>
    cur.executemany(q, p)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 255, in executemany
    self.errorhandler(self, TypeError, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 *

import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host='192.168.1.183', user='root', passwd='password', db='test', charset='utf8')
cur = db.cursor()

q = """INSERT INTO test2 (id, value)
    VALUES (%s, %s)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY
    UPDATE value=%s
    """

p = [(1, 7, 7)]

# failed
cur.executemany(q, p)

# working
for i in p:
    cur.execute(q, i)

db.commit()
db.close()
```

Database:

```
CREATE TABLE `test2` (
  `id` bigint(8) NOT NULL,
  `value` float NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `test2`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `test2`
  MODIFY `id` bigint(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

I am trying mariadb-10.2, pymysql but anyway error occurs in Stretch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *may* work:  Change `UPDATE value=%s` to `UPDATE value=VALUES(value)` and get rid of the last `7` in the array.

If that does not work, then here is more discussion:

I think `executemany` is trying to build

```
INSERT ...
     VALUES (...),
            (...),
            (...);
```

But it does not know how to convert the IODKU syntax into a repeated list like that.  Bottom line: you can probably use `executemany` with `INSERT`, `INSERT IGNORE`, `REPLACE`, but not IODKU.

For IODKU to work, Stretch needs to be smart enough to do this:

```
INSERT INTO test2 (id, value)
    VALUES
        (%s, %s),
        (%s, %s),
        (%s, %s),
        (%s, %s),
        etc
    ON DUPLICATE KEY
    UPDATE value=VALUES(value)
```

Note that the repetition is in the middle, not on the end, as in the other cases.  However *you* have to use the `VALUES()` pseudo-function to avoid the `%s` in the `UPDATE` clause.

Comment: Many thanks! It's working:

```INSERT INTO test2 (id, value)
    VALUES (%s, %s)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY
    UPDATE value=VALUES(value)```

But I do not understand why the same code works in Wheezy and Jessie but doesn't work in Stretch. I have the same versions of MySQLdb/pymysql.
Possible `mariadb-client-10.1` has incompatible changes with `mariadb-client-10.1`. But I could not find out something info.

Comment: I think the code is entirely on the client side.  Sounds like Stretch is buggy?  But that is an OS name, correct?  The OS should not be involved.  If it is in Buster, write a bug report against Debian.